# Grep command with "${sta}~${stp}!d"

Tags: bash, sed

I have come across the following code.  What is `"${sta}~${stp}!d"` supposed to do?

```
grep --null -r -l "${isufx[@]}" -e "$ptrn" -- "${fdir[@]}" |
  sed -z "${sta}~${stp}!d"
```

Comment: That depends on what the variables `sta` and `stp` are set to.

Comment: They are integers.  It occurs to me that it might be skipping some of the files being passed by the `find` command.

Answer (score 0):

From https://www.gnu.org/software/sed/manual/sed.html#Numeric-Addresses :

```
first~step

This GNU extension matches every stepth line starting with line first.
```

Comment: Perhaps add: And `!d` means don't delete the line. Example: with first=21 and step=2 delete all lines except the odd ones starting at line 21.